# Grouping based on condition in xsl 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to group based on OperationID and then again group based on COMBINATION_CODE  within the OperationID. But COMBINATION_CODE may also have empty tag. The below style sheet is grouping COMBINATION_CODE as expected only if the value is present in COMBINATION_CODE. If empty tag is present, irrespective of OperationID, it is grouping all the empty  COMBINATION_CODE records together. Please find the sample input:

```
<root>
   <records>
        <record>
             <OperationID>13</OperationID>
             <COMBINATION_CODE>c</COMBINATION_CODE>
             <GroupID>00</GroupID>
             <UTC_TIME>2018-12-06</UTC_TIME>
             <ID>123456789</ID>
             <DocumentID>ShowOperationCode20181206071249</DocumentID>
             <AllGroupID>JTH</AllGroupID>
             <AllID>B21B1</AllID>
        </record>
        <record>
             <OperationID>13</OperationID>
             <COMBINATION_CODE>c</COMBINATION_CODE>
             <GroupID>00</GroupID>
             <UTC_TIME>2018-12-06</UTC_TIME>
             <ID>123456789</ID>
             <DocumentID>ShowOperationCode20181206071249</DocumentID>
             <AllGroupID>JTT</AllGroupID>
             <AllID>B21FB</AllID>
        </record>
        <record>
             <OperationID>13</OperationID>
             <COMBINATION_CODE/>
             <GroupID>00</GroupID>
             <UTC_TIME>2018-12-06</UTC_TIME>
             <ID>123456789</ID>
             <DocumentID>ShowOperationCode20181206071249</DocumentID>
             <AllGroupID>JTT</AllGroupID>
             <AllID>B21FC</AllID>
        </record>       
        <record>
             <OperationID>14</OperationID>
             <COMBINATION_CODE/>
             <GroupID>01</GroupID>
             <UTC_TIME>2018-12-06</UTC_TIME>
             <ID>123456788</ID>
             <DocumentID>ShowOperationCode20181206071250</DocumentID>
             <AllGroupID>KTH</AllGroupID>
             <AllID>BFFHT</AllID>
        </record>
    </records>
</root>
```

Expected output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Show releaseID="5.4.4" xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5">
        <DataArea>
            <LOperations>
                <LOperationsDetail>
                        <LOperationID>13</LOperationID>
                        <Combinations>
                        <combinationCode>c</combinationCode><!-- combinationCode is grouped and each record is present inside VLaborAllowance -->
                        <VLaborAllowance  xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5" >
                                <VIGroup>
                                    <GID>JTH</GID>
                                    <VID>B21B1</VID>
                                </VIGroup>
                        </VLaborAllowance>
                        <VLaborAllowance  xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5" >
                                <VIGroup>
                                    <GID>JTT</GID>
                                    <VID>B21FB</VID>
                                </VIGroup>
                        </VLaborAllowance>
                        </Combinations>
                        <Combinations>
                        <combinationCode/><!--empty tag should present in separate combination-->
                        <VLaborAllowance  xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5" >
                                <VIGroup>
                                    <GID>JTT</GID>
                                    <VID>B21FC</VID>
                                </VIGroup>
                            </VLaborAllowance>
                        </Combinations>
                    </LOperationsDetail>
                    <LOperationsDetail>
                        <LOperationID>KTH</LOperationID>
                        <Combinations>
                        <combinationCode/>
                        <VLaborAllowance  xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5" >
                                <VIGroup>
                                    <GID>KTH</GID>
                                    <VID>BFFHT</VID>
                                </VIGroup>
                            </VLaborAllowance>
                        </Combinations>
                    </LOperationsDetail>
            </star:LOperations>
        </star:DataArea>
    </star:Show>
```

Used  stylesheet :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="opcode" match="record" use="OperationID" />
    <xsl:key name="combination" match="record" use="COMBINATION_CODE" />    
    <xsl:template match="root/records">
    <Show releaseID="5.4.4" xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5">
        <DataArea>
            <LOperations>
                <xsl:for-each select="record[count(. | key('opcode', OperationID)[1]) = 1]" >          
                    <LOperationsDetail>
                        <LOperationID><xsl:value-of select="OperationID"/></LOperationID>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('opcode',OperationID)[count(. | key('combination', COMBINATION_CODE)[1]) = 1]" >
                        <Combinations>
                            <combinationCode><xsl:value-of select="COMBINATION_CODE"/></combinationCode>
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('combination', COMBINATION_CODE)">
                            <VLaborAllowance  xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5" >
                                <VIGroup>
                                    <GID><xsl:value-of select="AllGroupID" /></GID>
                                    <VID><xsl:value-of select="AllID" /></VID>
                                </VIGroup>
                            </VLaborAllowance>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </Combinations>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </LOperationsDetail>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </LOperations>
        </DataArea>
    </Show>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Show xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5" releaseID="5.4.4">
  <DataArea>
    <LOperations>
      <LOperationsDetail>
        <LOperationID>13</LOperationID>
        <Combinations>
          <combinationCode>c</combinationCode>
          <VLaborAllowance>
            <VIGroup>
              <GID>JTH</GID>
              <VID>B21B1</VID>
            </VIGroup>
          </VLaborAllowance>
          <VLaborAllowance>
            <VIGroup>
              <GID>JTT</GID>
              <VID>B21FB</VID>
            </VIGroup>
          </VLaborAllowance>
        </Combinations>
        <Combinations>
          <combinationCode/>
          <VLaborAllowance>
            <VIGroup>
              <GID>JTT</GID>
              <VID>B21FC</VID>
            </VIGroup>
          </VLaborAllowance>
          <VLaborAllowance>
            <VIGroup>
              <GID>KTH</GID>
              <VID>BFFHT</VID>
            </VIGroup>
          </VLaborAllowance>
        </Combinations>
      </LOperationsDetail>
      <LOperationsDetail>
        <LOperationID>14</LOperationID>
      </LOperationsDetail>
    </LOperations>
  </DataArea>
</Show>
```

Comment: Your stylesheet errors out: `<Show releaseID="5.4.4" xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5">` does not match `</star:Show>` and so on.

Comment: Also it's not clear if there can be more that one `COMBINATION_CODE` in the same `OperationID`. if not, why don't you just use the same key. If yes, then you have a more serious problem than just empty `COMBINATION_CODE`, because your current method will only get the first subgroup.

Comment: I have edited the stylesheet.I need to group the COMBINATION_CODE within OperationID. As of now, operationid is grouped together and inside that also COMBINATION_CODE is getting grouped correctly. Only problem is if the COMBINATION_CODE is empty, irrespective of operationcode, it is grouping all the COMBINATION_CODE in the first set of operationcode. Please find the output I am getting right now

Comment: Please answer my question:  can there be more that one `COMBINATION_CODE` (not counting empty) in the same `OperationID`?

Comment: Yes , there can be more than one COMBINATION_CODE in same operationID

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a sub-group based on `COMBINATION_CODE` within the current group based on `OperationID`, you must include `OperationID` in the sub-group's key definition:

```
<xsl:key name="combination" match="record" use="concat(COMBINATION_CODE, '|', OperationID)" />
```

as well as when calling the key:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="opcode" match="record" use="OperationID" />
<xsl:key name="combination" match="record" use="concat(COMBINATION_CODE, '|', OperationID)" />   

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <Show releaseID="5.4.4" xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5">
        <DataArea>
            <LOperations>
                <!-- for each distinct OperationID -->
                <xsl:for-each select="records/record[count(. | key('opcode', OperationID)[1]) = 1]" >          
                    <LOperationsDetail>
                        <LOperationID><xsl:value-of select="OperationID"/></LOperationID>
                        <!-- for each distinct COMBINATION_CODE in the current group -->
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('opcode', OperationID)[count(. | key('combination', concat(COMBINATION_CODE, '|', OperationID))[1]) = 1]" >
                            <Combinations>
                                <combinationCode><xsl:value-of select="COMBINATION_CODE"/></combinationCode>
                                <!-- get current sub-group -->
                                <xsl:for-each select="key('combination', concat(COMBINATION_CODE, '|', OperationID))">
                                    <VLaborAllowance  xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5" >
                                        <VIGroup>
                                            <GID><xsl:value-of select="AllGroupID" /></GID>
                                            <VID><xsl:value-of select="AllID" /></VID>
                                        </VIGroup>
                                    </VLaborAllowance>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </Combinations>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </LOperationsDetail>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </LOperations>
        </DataArea>
    </Show>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. But when i apply this logic in my original xml, I am not getting any values inside LOperations. If i replace these lines <xsl:for-each select="records/record[count(. | key('opcode', OperationID)[1]) = 1]" >  with <xsl:for-each select="record[count(. | key('opcode', OperationID)[1]) = 1]" >  again i am ended up with same grouping issue.

Comment: AFAICT, the result is identical to your expected output: http://xsltransform.net/asnmyH